# How create my own assertions for casperJS

Tags: casperjs

Is there a way to create custom assertions for casperJS? The only thing that I got worked is something like this:

```
casper.test.assertIsChecked = function(selector, msg) {
  var isChecked = !this.casper.getElementsAttribute(selector, 'checked')
  this.assertTruthy(isChecked, msg);
}
```

But its a bit hacky to just add it to test object and it lacks from proper error message.